# Drupal 7 - i18n menu item langcode

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

Hello i have multilingual site. The site was build on Drupal 7.15 and i18n module. Couple of days ago I have updated core and all contrib modules. Everything works kind a nice but I have noticed when I add new menu item it doesn't show.

I debugged this behaviour and I have found out that all menu items added BEFORE updated has parameter "langcode" with proper language, but all items added AFTER update have no "langcode".

Site has condition which filters menu items according to menu item's "langcode". If I remove this condition it actually works nice.

So my question is. Do I understand it right that menu items with proper language are now selected in some preprocess so "langcode" is no longer needed?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Your guess sounds right. Have a look at the issue queue of the i18n project (look for "menu langcode" as terms) and you'll probably confirm your guess.  See : https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/i18n?text=menu+langcode&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=7.x&component=All

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually still cant find clear answer. There is lot of implication that it's probably as I described but i cant find clear confirmation.

Comment: Your guess sounds right. Can you just try to remove your custom filtering and see how it goes ?

Comment: I tried yesterday on testing server and it seems to works nice. Today i deployed changes to real servers and every works. So I thinks my theory is not bad :-) Thanks a lot for your consultation.